# s;umproduct with multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula, texel

Im trying to use sumproduct with multiple criteria 1 in the first column and  2 critera in the second column, lets say apples and pears,  I've tried using the '+' or syntax which seems a bit hit and miss or maybe im just not using it correctly.  Can I add 2 function together sort of sumproduct(--(dddd=aaa),--(adkjdkf)+sumproduct(--(akdd),--(aldkfk))

Richard

Answer (score 0):

You are close on the second guess. Try using conditional logic within the `SUMPRODUCT`.

Something like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ColumnA=criteria), --(ColumnB=criteria), range1, range2)`

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have got it working, using 'OR (+i), or adding two complete formulas together,  1)  SUMPRODUCT(--(G10:G17="tom"),--(H10:H17="north"),--(I10:I17="pear")+(I10:I17="apple"),J10:J17,K10:K17)   2)SUMPRODUCT(--(G10:G17="tom"),--(H10:H17="north"),--(I10:I17="pear"),J10:J17,K10:K17)+SUMPRODUCT(--(G10:G17="tom"),--(H10:H17="north"),--(I10:I17="apple"),J10:J17,K10:K17)
Any further guidance greatfully  received.